# sql select query using inner join

Tags: mysql

I was wondering why my code isn't working. I'm trying to retrieve all offers of a listing only.

```
CREATE DATABASE  IF NOT EXISTS `assignment_db`;
USE `assignment_db`;

CREATE TABLE USER_LIST(
id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
userName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
email varchar(100) NOT NULL,
registeredDate timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);


create table listing_list(
id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
itemName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
itemDescription VARCHAR(254) NOT NULL,
price DECIMAL(4,2) NOT NULL,
fk_poster_id int references USER_LIST(id),
created_at timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);

create table offer_list(
id int(6) Unsigned auto_increment Primary key,
offer int,
fk_listing_id int references listing_list(id),
fk_offeror_id int references user_list(id),
created_at timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);

insert into user_list (userName, email) values ('John','johnnyboi@123.com');
insert into user_list (userName, email) values ('Tom','Tommyboi@123.com');
insert into listing_list (itemName,itemDescription, price) values ( 'Pen', 'A long delicate pen.',' 1.50 ');
insert into listing_list (itemName,itemDescription, price) values ( 'Pencil', 'A long delicate pencil.',' 0.50 ');
insert into offer_list (offer,fk_listing_id,fk_offeror_id) values ('200','2','3');
insert into offer_list (offer,fk_listing_id,fk_offeror_id) values ('200','1','1');

select * from listing_list 
inner join offer_list on listing_list.fk_listing_id = offer_list.id;
```

Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Comment: Define *not working* Are you getting any error message ? What are the expected result and the current one ?

Comment: Have you checked my answer? Let me know if that resolves your issue

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood you correctly, you want something like this (see fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0844f687f54c0fc301a613b3e131444f)). Note that I changed some of the numbers to make it easier to follow the flow of the query:

```
insert into user_list (id, userName, email) values (10, 'John','johnnyboi@123.com');
insert into user_list (id, userName, email) values (20, 'Tom','Tommyboi@123.com');
```

and

```
insert into listing_list (itemName,itemDescription, price, fk_poster_id) 
values ( 'Pen', 'A long delicate pen.',' 1.50 ', 10);
insert into listing_list (itemName,itemDescription, price, fk_poster_id) 
values ( 'Pencil', 'A long delicate pencil.',' 0.50 ', 20);
```

and

```
insert into offer_list (offer,fk_listing_id,fk_offeror_id) 
values ('200','1', 10);
insert into offer_list (offer,fk_listing_id,fk_offeror_id) 
values ('200','2', 20);
```

Then I ran the query:

```
SELECT 
  u.id,
  u.username,
  u.email,
  l.id, 
  l.itemName, 
  l.itemDescription,l.price,
  l.fk_poster_id,
  l.created_at,
  o.offer,
  o.fk_listing_id
FROM user_list u
JOIN listing_list l ON u.id = l.fk_poster_id
JOIN offer_list o ON u.id = o.fk_offeror_id;
```

Result:

```
id  username    email   id  itemName    itemDescription price   fk_poster_id    created_at  offer   fk_listing_id
10  John    johnnyboi@123.com   1   Pen A long delicate pen.    1.50    10  2019-12-23 11:21:10 200 1
20   Tom    Tommyboi@123.com    2   Pencil  A long delicate pencil. 0.50    20  2019-12-23 11:21:10 200 2
```

Some of the result fields are redundant - I left them in so that you could see the reasoning. Can I recommend that in future a) you don't bother with backticks for MySQL anymore - they are no longer required and are a pain  to type. Also, when dealing with numberic values - even though MySQL (**weirdly**) supports this, that you do **not** put numbers in single quotes - it makes the SQL more difficult to read using many SQL formatting tools.

Answer (score -1):

```
select * from listing_list inner join offer_list on listing_list.id = offer_list.fk_listing_id
```

You have taken the wrong table names.

For more details, check https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp

The basic syntax for inner join:

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2
ON table1.column_name = table2.column_name;
```

> If you want to select the data only form 1 listing, you can do it
>   like:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    listing_list
INNER JOIN offer_list ON listing_list.id = offer_list.fk_listing_id
WHERE
    listing_list.id = 1
```